# How to manage ERROR 401 when click on Cancel of Active Directory Authentication - Web Application

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, .net-6.0

I'm sorry if this question is stupid, but I'm new in this field.

I have a web application who uses the Windows Authentication. I've created a login page and, after click the LOGIN button, the default Chrome [login popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9DQE.png) appears.

But if I click on "Annulla" (Cancel), it shows the error 401 message (*401 - Permission Denied - Access denied due to invalid credentials.*) instead of the login page.

I want that after click on Cancel, it will return on login page instead of error 401 default page.

I know that this may be managed by IIS tool, but can I manage this situation through code?

I'm using MVC .NET 6

Thank you and have a good day

Comment: Initially you are an Anonymous user without credentials until you enter a username and password.  So you have to enable Anonymous.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?force_isolation=true&view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Already added `[AllowAnonymous]` tag on Login method in Controller who returns the view Login. Is that enough? I don't think so, because I obtain the 401 if I click on Cancel.

Comment: You have to make two request.  One two login which returns a cookie authentication and then make second connection with cookie : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?force_isolation=true&view=aspnetcore-7.0#create-an-authentication-cookie